# Stuck on getting onclick() to work

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically when i run my application it displays the titles on the listview correctly but i then want to have a onclick() that displays the price when each title is clicked

I thought doing something like his would work but it doesnt :( anyhelp would be appreciated

```
textbox.Text = listview1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
```

I am completly new to this so i apoligize if the question sounds noobish.

xml file:

```
<books>
  <type>
    <price>2.50</price>
    <title>Harry</title>
  </type>
  <type>
    <price>2.70</price>
    <title>bob</title>
  </type>
</books>
```

Code:

```
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("XMLfile1.xml");
        XmlNodeType type;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            type = reader.NodeType;
            if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "title")
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    listView1.Items.Add(reader.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why are you populating the ListView when the selected index changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
textbox.Text = listview1.SelectedValue;
```